# How to delete an old Apple ID on iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, email, apple-id

For a short time, I'm reverting back to my old iPhone.
I entered my current Apple ID (the one with email address). A long time ago, Apple ID wasn't an email address.

The pop-up "Sign in to iTunes Store" keeps showing. How can one delete the old Apple ID (not an email address) without resetting?

Answer (score 1):

I’m not sure what you mean by resetting but if you go to https://appleid.apple.com/ from a computer you can manage Apple ID’s.

Also here’s a link to an Apple discussion group with similar issue. 
https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5362309?language=en

Hope this helped.